# I have deleted a Pod from Pods Library but still it's showing this error and not running

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have deleted RoundCornerProgress Pods from Pods library in Xcode but after that when I run the project it shows this error. How can I resolve this problem?

[image: Here is the Image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pod install --no-repo-update` command.

Remove the pod that you don't need from your pod file and then run this command.

This command will essentially remove the unwanted libraries without affecting other dependencies. Clean and build your project after doing this and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pod deintegrate` to remove all traces of CocoaPods from the Xcode project.